# Homotopy Visualization

Tags: visualization, topology

I noticed that both the lower cased 'i' and the Apple logo  are topologically equivalent to  the disjoint union of two closed discs.

[image]

I'd like to animate a homotopy from the left to the right, can this be done in Mathematica 10 with built in functions?

Comment: I guess you mean a homotopy, actually.

Comment: Yeah, they are homeomorphic, but you are right, it's the homotopy that I want.

Comment: I did something like [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/393416/are-these-2-graphs-isomorphic/393520#393520) to illustrate graph isomorphism.  That's much simpler, though, really. Shouldn't be to hard to grab a set of points describing the boundaries of the objects but it might be tricky to maintain the topological integrity throughout the animation.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Here's a way to morph the boundaries.  After finding the boundaries by [`Thinning`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Thinning.html) of the result of [`EdgeDetect`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/EdgeDetect.html), [`FindCurvePath`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FindCurvePath.html) finds a sequence of points that traces a path around each segment.  [`MorphologicalComponents`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MorphologicalComponents.html) numbers the component left to right, top to bottom, so that `1` is the apple leaf, `2` is the i-dot, `3` is the apple body, and `4` is the i-stem (`5`, `6` are the equal sign).  We can then interpolate a path around each boundary (`cIFNs`). Finally we interpolate between the corresponding paths `(1-p)... + p...`.

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7Fka.png"];
boundaries = Thinning @ EdgeDetect[img, 1];
comp = MorphologicalComponents @ boundaries;

pdata = Position[comp, #].{{0, -1}, {1, 0}} & /@ {1, 2, 3, 4};

curves = FindCurvePath /@ pdata;

cIFNs = MapThread[
   Interpolation[
     Transpose@{Rescale@Range@Length@First@#2, #1[[First@#2]]}, 
     PeriodicInterpolation -> True] &, {pdata, curves}
   ];

(* offset between middle of apple and middle of "i" *)
offset = First @ Differences[Mean @ Through[{Min, Max}[#]] & /@ pdata[[{3, 4}, All, 1]]];

Manipulate[
  ParametricPlot[{
     (1 - p) cIFNs[[1]][t] + p (cIFNs[[2]][t] + {-offset, 0}),
     (1 - p) cIFNs[[3]][t] + p (cIFNs[[4]][t] + {-offset, 0})},
   {t, 0, 1},
   Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 
      Total[Through[{Min, Max}[pdata[[3, All, 1]]]]]}, {-Last@
        ImageDimensions[img], 0}}],
  {p, 0, 1}
  ]
```

[image]

To morph the areas, post-process the plot by replacing `Line` with `Polygon`:

```
ParametricPlot[...] /. Line -> Polygon
```

One can omit the frame, of course.

Comment: This is by far the greatest solution I've seen, excellent work!

Comment: WOW, wicked answer! +1

Comment: Here's a neat way to see the evolution: `ParametricPlot3D[{Append[(1 - p) cIFNs[[1]][t] + 
    p (cIFNs[[2]][t] + {-offset, 0}), 200 p], 
  Append[(1 - p) cIFNs[[3]][t] + p (cIFNs[[4]][t] + {-offset, 0}), 
   200 p]}, {p, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}, Axes -> False, Boxed -> False]`

Comment: Or use `-200p` instead of `200p` to see the evolution in reverse order.

Comment: Seeing the homotopy between the apple logo and the equals sign is pretty neat too. `pdata = Position[comp, #].{{0, -1}, {1, 0}} & /@ {1, 5, 3, 6}`

Answer (score 54):

One way to do it would be to use glyphs.  We can extract the curves that make up the two characters as follows:

```
a = First@First@Last@First@First@
       ImportString[ExportString[
         Style[FromCharacterCode[61440], 24, FontFamily -> "Baskerville Old Face"],
       "PDF"], "PDF", "TextMode" -> "Outlines"];

b = First@First@Last@First@First@
       ImportString[ExportString[
         Style["i", 24, Bold, FontFamily -> "Courier New"],
       "PDF"], "PDF", "TextMode" -> "Outlines"];
```

These each give a `FilledCurve`, which I presume defines a spline.  The documentation doesn't seem to explain the format given here.  But it appears to be a bunch of control information (degree? knots?), then a bunch of points.  But we shall not let ignorance stop us.

The main challenge now is morphing one curve into another.  Since the apple logo has more points than the 'i', we shall simply force a bunch of repeated points in the 'i' curve to aid in the transition. First grab the data:

```
control = First@a;
pa = Last@a;
pb = Last@b;
magic = {{2, 8, 3, 8, 2}, {2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1,
    2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2}};
```

Then repeat some points in the 'i':

```
newb = Map[Sequence @@ ConstantArray[First@#, Last@#] &, Thread /@ Thread[{pb, magic}], {2}];
```

Now we can just do a simple linear transition between the two:

```
Table[Graphics@FilledCurve[control, pa + t (newb - pa)], {t, 0, 1, 0.1}]
```

Using a sinusoidal `t`, and some well chosen `Export` options (exercise left to the reader), we get:

[image: applemorph]

Answer (score 44):

Let us do it purely by image-processing. The main idea is to use `DistanceTransform` here.

```
{img1, img2} = ImageResize[#, Scaled[3]] & /@ 
   Import /@ {"https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKHo5.png", 
        "https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFGR4.png"}
```

The signed distances to the boundaries of all morphological components are

```
dist = ImageData@ImageSubtract[DistanceTransform@Image@#, 
          DistanceTransform@ColorNegate@Image@#] & /@ 
       ComponentMeasurements[#, "Mask"][[All, 2]] &@
     MorphologicalComponents@ColorNegate@Binarize@# & /@ {img1, img2};

Map[ImageAdjust@Image@# &, dist, {2}] // Grid
```

[image]

It is remain is to take a linear composition of these distances

```
top[t_] := ColorNegate@Image@Total[UnitStep[# (1 - t) + #2 t] & @@@ Transpose@dist];

Export["anim.gif", Join[#, Reverse@#] &@ 
   Table[ImageResize[top[t], Scaled[1/3]], {t, 0, 1, 0.01}]];
```

[image]

Comment: I'm afraid this technique doesn't always produce a homotopy. For example, try interpolating a small disk in the lower left corner to a small disk in the upper right; it will disappear along the way.

Comment: @RahulNarain, yes, if there is no intersection then there is such an artifact. One can avoid it by introducing a moving center and applying the algorithm above relative to the moving center. Like in physics: motion of the center of mass and the relative motion.     If you are interesting, I can add corresponding lines to the code.

Comment: I think translating the center of mass will not help with these images: http://i.stack.imgur.com/2ob00.png, http://i.stack.imgur.com/RIL4B.png. But perhaps I'm being too critical.

Comment: @RahulNarain Yes :) It's a very difficult task to deal with such images. Spirals will be even more difficult. Thank you for the deep insight in my answer!

Comment: The big benefit of this approach is that can create a smooth mapping between shapes where a homotopy doesn't exist at all, e.g. mapping a "P" to an "F", or an "O" to an "i". I only discovered your answer until I hacked it down myself. Nevertheless +1 for this nice answer.