# Morphing one closed curve into another

Tags: image-processing, animation

How would I go about creating an animation of one smooth nonintersecting closed curve being continuously morphed into another closed curve? Additionally, the curves are not given analytically, but are taken from a .png image. One particular example is shown below --- I want to get the second curve from the first (little circles inside the shapes can be ignored). Any advice would be much appreciated! [image]

Comment: Hi, take a look at [Homotopy Visualization](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/59463/5478)

Comment: Thanks, that looks like exactly what I need!

Comment: @Kuba I have tried some test examples (two larger objects with two smaller objects above them) with the top answer in the linked thread (others do not produce a homotopy) and it seems to break down regularly with the error message "Interpolation::per: In dimension 1 the data at the endpoints of the fundamental period are not equal." I am not very experienced with Mathematica, so I tried to tweak it to no avail. Could you or anyone else provide a working example for a particular case of this image: http://i.imgur.com/xFbSVIK.png?