# Project map to a particular shape

Tags: finite-element-method, geometry, computational-geometry, geodesy, projection

I want to project a map to a particular shape, like a circle or ellipse. For example, let's imagine we want to project a map of the continental United states so that its outline is that of a circle. The basic strategy I have is illustrated below:

[image]

To project the outline is easy, the geographic center is at the center of the circle and the perimeter is divided into small sectors, perhaps 1-degree each. Then the points of the perimeter are equally divided within their sector and mapped to the corresponding sector on the perimeter of the circle.

To project the interior points of the map is the tricky part on which I need advice. In the image an example of such a point is shown as a blue dot. Then the procedure I have in mind for projecting it is as follows.

(1) Find the point on the geodesic perimeter of the United States which is closest to the point to be projected. This is indicated as a red dot in the illustrative image above.

(2) In the geodesic data (a sphere), draw an imaginary line to the red dot, the closest point.

(3) In the geodesic data (a sphere), draw two lines going outwards at 120 degrees in either direction relative to the red line. These two lines are shown in green. Find the points where these lines intersect the geodesic perimeter of the United States. These two points are shown as green dots.

(4) To project the point of interest, the blue dot, start at the red dot and move inwards along a line at the same angle as in the original geodesic data. So, for example, in illustrative image the red line is at on a bearing of of about 10 degrees relative to the red dot. That same angle is adopted in the projected image.

(5) To locate the blue dot, a ratio is determined between the sum of geodesic distances of the two green lines and the distance of the red line. Then, in the projected image, the blue dot is placed so that this ratio is the same. Note that the green lines will not be at 120-degrees from the red line in the projected image.

My question is whether this is a reasonable strategy for doing this kind of projection, and how I would go about implementing it in Mathematica.

Comment: You can use this: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/59463/5478

Comment: Show us the code you have already tried, your definitions for maps  and shapes and so on. This site is not about algorithms, but about Wolfram Mathematica programming so please [edit] your question to make it explicitly about  programming in Mathematica/Wolfram Language . Include a [formatted](https://wolfr.am/v57OLJu4) minimum example of the code you are working on.

Comment: @Kuba That is interesting, but it is not appropriate for a map transformation because the points move proportionately to the length of the perimeter which results in distortion. For example, in the case of the United States, the area around the great lakes would become gigantic in the projected map due to the longer coastline in that area.

Comment: @TylerDurden it is hard to avoid distortions here, isn't it? And you only mentioned your preferences somewhere in comments below answers. But yes, I agree it is only a quick start tip rather than full solution.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If the domain $\varOmega$ of the county is simply connect, one might use the [Riemannian mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_mapping_theorem#A_sketch_proof).

For $z_0 \in \varOmega^\circ$, we make the following ansatz for the holomorphic map $f \colon \varOmega \to D^2$:

$$ f(z) = (z-z_0) \, \operatorname{e}^{u(z) + \operatorname{i}\!v(z)}.$$

Then $|f(z)| = |z-z_0| \, \operatorname{e}^{u(z)}$ has to equal $1$ for all $z \in \partial \varOmega$. The Cauchy-Riemann equations imply that $u$ is the unique solution to the following Poisson problem:

$$\begin{cases}
   \Delta u(z) &= 0, &z \in \varOmega^\circ,\\
   u(z) &= - \log( |z-z_0|), &z \in \partial \varOmega.
\end{cases}$$

#Implementation of $u$

This can be easily solved with the finite element method. Here is how this can be done (I chose a different country because the boundary curve of the USA seemed to have self-intersections):

First, we discretize the interior of the domain:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
p = Most@Cases[CountryData["Germany", "Shape"], _Polygon, \[Infinity]][[1, 1, 1]];
R = ToElementMesh[
   BoundaryMeshRegion[p, Line[Partition[Range[Length[p]], 2, 1, 1]]],
   "MeshOrder" -> 1,
   MaxCellMeasure -> {1 -> .01}
   ];
R["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

```
(*Initialization of Finite Element Method*)

vd = NDSolve`VariableData[{"DependentVariables", "Space"} -> {{u}, {x, y}}];
sd = NDSolve`SolutionData[{"Space"} -> {R}];
cdata = InitializePDECoefficients[vd, sd,
   "DiffusionCoefficients" -> {{-IdentityMatrix[2]}},
   "MassCoefficients" -> {{1}}
   ];
bcdata = InitializeBoundaryConditions[vd, sd, {DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0., True]}];
mdata = InitializePDEMethodData[vd, sd];

(*Discretization*)
dpde = DiscretizePDE[cdata, mdata, sd];
dbc = DiscretizeBoundaryConditions[bcdata, mdata, sd];
{load, stiffness, damping, mass} = dpde["All"];
DeployBoundaryConditions[{load, stiffness}, dbc];

(*Preparation of Dirichlet boundary conditions for u*)

bndedges = R["BoundaryElements"][[1, 1]];
bndvertices = Sort@DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[bndedges]];
bpts = R["Coordinates"][[bndvertices]];
z0 = {0., 0.};
b = ConstantArray[0., Length[R["Coordinates"]]];
b[[bndvertices]] = -0.5 Log[Total[(bpts - ConstantArray[z0, Length[bpts]])^2, {2}]];

(*Solving the system and creating an interpolating function*)

solver = LinearSolve[stiffness, Method -> "Pardiso"];
uvals = solver[b];
ufun = ElementMeshInterpolation[{R}, uvals];
```

#Implementation of $v$

Due to the Cauchy-Riemann equations, we have

$$\operatorname{grad}(v) = J \, \operatorname{grad}(u),$$

where $J$ is the rotation of 90 degrees in counter clockwise orientation. Since $\varOmega$ is simply connected, up to a constant, $v$ is defined uniquely by this relation.
Hence, $v$ is also harmonic and is a solution of the following Neumann problem:

$$\begin{cases}
   \Delta v(z) &= 0, &z \in \varOmega^\circ,\\
   \frac{\partial v}{\partial \nu} (z) &= \langle \nu(z) , J \operatorname{grad}(u)(z) \rangle, &z \in \partial \varOmega.
\end{cases}$$
This pde is also amenable to a treatment with finite elements, although the preparation of the Neumann data needs a bit of fiddling. Notice that this second equation determines $v$ only up to a constant shift, which corresponds to the fact that $f$ is also unique up to a rotation of the disk.

```
(*Preparation of Neumann boundary conditions for v*)

gradu = {x, y} \[Function] Evaluate[D[ufun[x, y], {{x, y}, 1}]];
J = N@RotationMatrix[Pi/2];
p = R["Coordinates"];
{i, j} = Transpose[R["BoundaryElements"][[1, 1]]];
normalprojections = MapThreadDot[R["BoundaryNormals"][[1]], (gradu @@@ (0.5 (p[[i]] + p[[j]]))).(-J)];
boundaryedgelengths = Sqrt[Total[(p[[i]] - p[[j]])^2, {2}]];
{α, β} = Transpose[bndedges];
vertexbndedgeconnectivity = SparseArray[
   Transpose[{
      Join[α, β],
      Join[Range[Length[α]], Range[Length[β]]]
      }] -> 1,
   {Length[p], Length[bndedges]}
   ];

(*Solving the system and creating an interpolating function*)

b = vertexbndedgeconnectivity.(normalprojections boundaryedgelengths);
vvals = solver[b];
vfun = ElementMeshInterpolation[{R}, vvals];
```

Finally, we can obtain our approximation to the Riemannian mapping $f \colon \varOmega \to D^2$ by

```
f = {x, y} \[Function] Evaluate[
    ComplexExpand[
     ReIm[((x + I y) - (z0[[1]] + I z0[[2]])) Exp[ufun[x, y]] (Cos[vfun[x, y]] + I  Sin[vfun[x, y]])]
     ]
    ];
```

#Visualization

First, my favorite texture.

[image]

Now, the actual plots, using basically $f$ as texture map for $\varOmega$. (Plots were obtained with resolution `MaxCellMeasure -> {1 -> .001}`.)

```
tex = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRwc1.png"];
texcoords = Transpose[{
    Total[(f @@@ p)^2, {2}],
    ConstantArray[0.5, Length[p]]
    }];
g = GraphicsRow[{
   Graphics[{Texture[tex],
     ElementMeshToGraphicsComplex[R, VertexTextureCoordinates -> texcoords]
     }],
   Graphics[{Texture[tex],
     ElementMeshToGraphicsComplex[R, VertexTextureCoordinates -> texcoords, 
      "CoordinateConversion" -> (f @@@ # &)]
     }]
   },
  ImageSize -> Full
  ]
```

[image]

Comment: This is close to how i pelting uv maps was done in 3D in the past. Triangulate the mesh then make every edge a spring with rest length at starting length, then force the boundaries to the shape you want (circle) then let the spring dynamics handle the interiors

Comment: @joojaa I just wanted to brag around with my classical education ;) Indeed, these things are standard tasks in the domain of texture mapping -- which does not mean that they were easy. The art is to guarantee that there are no flipped triangles. There is much more to it than it would fit into a single post.

Comment: small steps at a time ;)

Comment: Impressive final images!

Comment: Thanks Joseph, I really appreciate that!

Comment: Nice use of the low level FEM functions. You might be interested in `bndvertices === dbc["DirichletRows"]` and `normalprojections === 
 MapThreadDot[
  R["BoundaryNormals"][[1]], (gradu @@@ (0.5 (p[[i]] + p[[j]]))).(-J)]`. The first part can be done in `NDSolve` directly, I'd need think about a way to compute the normal for the second part to be done in `NDSolve`.

Comment: You can also use something like: `g = GraphicsRow[{Graphics[{Texture[tex], 
     ElementMeshToGraphicsComplex[R, 
      VertexTextureCoordinates -> texcoords]}], 
   Graphics[{Texture[tex], 
     ElementMeshToGraphicsComplex[R, 
      VertexTextureCoordinates -> texcoords, 
      "CoordinateConversion" -> (f[Sequence @@ ##] & /@ # &)]}]}, 
  ImageSize -> Full]`

Comment: @user21 Thank you so much! These tiny give-aways are actually really rewarding. The thing with the normal in the second equation was indeed bugging me for quite some time. Suggestions to simplify that are welcome.

Comment: Can you help me look at [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/283206/how-to-find-the-conformal-mapping-between-two-regions)? I am willing to discretize the arc into many polygons.

Comment: @yode Huh, this is so long ago... Simply discretize each domain and use the code above to find a conformal map from the discrete domains to the disk. You then only have to invert one of the resulting maps...

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher How do I revert one of these mappings? I have 100 bounties waiting for you. :)

Comment: Well, I have seen that. But unfortunately there are 100 other tasks without bounties but that are more pressing. =/

Answer (score 12):

You could use a [conformal map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_map)
based on the Koebe–Andreev–Thurston [circle packing theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_theorem).

---

[image]

          

<sup>Image from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_theorem).</sup>

---

It would not be a simple implementation from scratch, but it is very general,
mapping any shape to any other. Used in computer graphics quite a bit,
e.g., for texture mapping.

---

[image: CirclePacking]

          

<sup>Image from Peter Schröder.</sup>

---

Maybe visit Ken Stephenson's [circle packing web pages](http://www.circlepack.com/).

Comment: How is this implemented in Mathematica?

Comment: @TylerDurden: I only know it has been implemented (perhaps not in Mathematica). I added a link.

Comment: The Stephenson suffers from the same problem mentioned in my comment to the original question in that it distorts the map in areas of complex perimeters. The "great lakes problem". Eg in the example shown you can see how the gray dot is distorted. In a map projection this point should be relatively close to the coastline, because it is close to the coastline in the geodesic data. You may want to read the question more closely and think about how maps are designed to answer better..

Comment: @Tyler Any such mapping would introduce distortion of distances. Conformal maps have the nice property that they still preserve angles.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher For my purposes, I care most that the distance to the nearest point on the coastline are close to their geodesic distance. The angle to a distant point is not important.

Comment: @TylerDurden If I understand correctly, the map should have two properties: 1) a fixed scale (no distance distortion), and 2) all points 5 miles from a coastline (for example) would map to a circle. In this case, I'd think the center of your map would be the point in the USA most distant from any coastline, not the geographical center?

Comment: @barrycarter Well, the points of the perimeter do not have to be constructed with the same rule as the points on the interior. In the algorithm I used the perimeter is constructed differently than the interior. That may be a flawed method, but was my original thinking.

Comment: @TylerDurden Wouldn't that mean there's a "break" point at some distance from the perimeter where you switch from one algorithm to the other? It seems like things would get ugly there.

Comment: @barrycarter I don't think. If the perimeter as treated as dimensionless and has no visible features, then there is no visible discontinuity.