# How to find the conformal mapping between two regions

Tags: graphics, complex, regions, coordinate-transformation

As the [Riemann Mapping Theorem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannMappingTheorem.html), if both regions are simply connected regions, there must be a unique one-conformal mapping such that the points between the two regions correspond one-to-one. Can we find a conformal mapping from the red region to the blue region using *MMA*?

```
Show[RegionPlot[x^2 + y^3 < 2 && y > x^2, {x, -2, 3}, {y, -1, 4}, 
  PlotStyle -> Red], 
 Graphics[{Blue, Triangle[{{2, 1}, {2, 3}, {0, 4}}]}]]
```

[image]

---

ps: I can accept a polygon that discretes the arc into many sides.

Comment: Look in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/314189/how-to-find-a-conformal-map-of-the-unit-disk-on-a-given-simply-connected-domain for info.

Comment: Isn't this answer https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/178333/9469 completely solves your problem?

Comment: Sorry, unfortunately, I have no time for a detailed answer. Fortunately, there a people who have worked much more on this topic. Please have a look into this article by Mark Gillespie, Boris Springborn, and Keenan Crane: https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/3450626.3459763 and into the references therein. (There is also a video of Mark's talk.) I know, this is not the anwer you were looking for. But it is the best that I can give to you at the moment.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151202/discussion-on-question-by-yode-how-to-find-the-conformal-mapping-between-two-reg); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 15):

We can use PI algorithm described in the paper [Numerical Conformal Mapping with Rational Functions](https://doi.org/10.1007/s40315-020-00325-w).The function for conformal mapping can be computed as follows

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
reg1 = Triangle[{{2, 1}, {2, 3}, {0, 4}}]; reg2 = 
 ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^3 < 2 && y > x^2, {x, y}];

f[reg_, order_] := 
  Module[{Z, A, B, eq, g, vec, mat, sol, R1, z1, bndedges, 
    bndvertices, bpts, b, b0, aa, bb}, z1 = N@RegionCentroid[reg]; 
   R1 = ToElementMesh[reg, "MaxBoundaryCellMeasure" -> .01, 
     "MaxCellMeasure" -> .001]; 
   bndedges = R1["BoundaryElements"][[1, 1]];
   bndvertices = Sort@DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[bndedges]];
   bpts = R1["Coordinates"][[bndvertices]];
   b = ConstantArray[0., Length[R1["Coordinates"]]];
   b0 = b[[
      bndvertices]] = -0.5 Log[
       Total[(bpts - ConstantArray[z1, Length[bpts]])^2, {2}]];
   
   With[{nn = order}, 
    Z = {x, y} |-> Table[ComplexExpand[(x + I y)^n], {n, 0, nn}];
    A = Array[aa, {nn + 1}]; B = Array[bb, {nn + 1}];
    g = {x, y} |-> ComplexExpand[(A + I B) . Z[x, y]]];
   
   eq = -b0 + (g[#[[1]] - z1[[1]], #[[2]] - z1[[2]]] & /@ bpts) /. 
     I -> 0;
   
   {vec, mat} = CoefficientArrays[Join[{bb[1]}, eq], Join[A, B]];
   
   sol = LeastSquares[mat, -vec];
   With[{nn = order}, 
    Do[aa[i] = sol[[i]]; 
     bb[i] = sol[[nn + 1 + i]];, {i, nn + 1}]]; {{x, y} |-> 
     ReIm[Evaluate[
       ComplexExpand[((x + I y) - (z1[[1]] + I  z1[[2]]))  Exp[
          g[x - z1[[1]], y - z1[[2]]]]]]], {x, y} |-> 
     ComplexExpand[(A + I B) . Z[x, y]], z1, R1}];
```

Example of usage

```
{f1, g1, z1, mesh1} = f[reg1, 32];

{Plot3D[Evaluate[g1[x - z1[[1]], y - z1[[2]]]] // Re, 
  Element[{x, y}, reg1], ColorFunction -> Hue], 
 Plot3D[Evaluate[g1[x - z1[[1]], y - z1[[2]]]] // Im, 
  Element[{x, y}, reg1], ColorFunction -> Hue]}
```

[image: Figure 1]

```
{f2, g2, z2, mesh2} = f[reg2, 32];

{Plot3D[Evaluate[g2[x - z2[[1]], y - z2[[2]]]] // Re, 
  Element[{x, y}, reg2], ColorFunction -> Hue], 
 Plot3D[Evaluate[g2[x - z2[[1]], y - z2[[2]]]] // Im, 
  Element[{x, y}, reg2], ColorFunction -> Hue]}
```

[image: Figure 2]
Mesh lines on `reg2`

```
rho2 = ContourPlot[Abs[f2[x, y]], Element[{x, y}, reg2], 
   Contours -> Range[.1, .9, .1], 
   ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Hue[1/3, 1, 1, .5]], 
   AspectRatio -> Automatic];

arg2 = ContourPlot[Arg[f2[x, y]], Element[{x, y}, reg2], 
   Contours -> Pi  Range[-.8, .8, .1], 
   ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Hue[1/3, 1, 1, .25]], 
   AspectRatio -> Automatic, ExclusionsStyle -> Black];

Show[rho2, arg2]
```

[image: Figure 3]

Mesh lines on `reg1`

```
rho1 = ContourPlot[Abs[f1[x, y]], Element[{x, y}, reg1], 
  Contours -> Range[.1, .9, .1], 
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Hue[1/3, 1, 1, .5]], 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic];

arg1 = ContourPlot[Arg[f1[x, y]], Element[{x, y}, reg1], 
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Hue[1/3, 1, 1, .25]], 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic, Contours -> Pi Range[-.8, .8, .1], 
  PlotPoints -> 50];
Show[rho1, arg1]
```

[image: Figure 4]

**First attempt.**
We can try approach that recommended by yarchik and implemented by
Henrik Schumacher [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/178316/project-map-to-a-particular-shape/178333#178333). We have

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
reg1 = Triangle[{{2, 1}, {2, 3}, {0, 4}}]; reg2 = 
 ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^3 < 2 && y > x^2, {x, y}];
f[reg_] := 
 Module[{R, p, z0, ufun, vfun}, 
  R = ToElementMesh[reg, "MeshOrder" -> 1, 
    "MaxBoundaryCellMeasure" -> .01, "MaxCellMeasure" -> .001];
  z0 = N@RegionCentroid[reg];
  (*Initialization of Finite Element Method*)
  vd = NDSolve`VariableData[{"DependentVariables", 
      "Space"} -> {{u}, {x, y}}];
  sd = NDSolve`SolutionData[{"Space"} -> {R}];
  cdata = 
   InitializePDECoefficients[vd, sd, 
    "DiffusionCoefficients" -> {{-IdentityMatrix[2]}}, 
    "MassCoefficients" -> {{1}}];
  bcdata = 
   InitializeBoundaryConditions[vd, 
    sd, {DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0., True]}];
  mdata = InitializePDEMethodData[vd, sd];
  
  (*Discretization*)
  dpde = DiscretizePDE[cdata, mdata, sd];
  dbc = DiscretizeBoundaryConditions[bcdata, mdata, sd];
  {load, stiffness, damping, mass} = dpde["All"];
  DeployBoundaryConditions[{load, stiffness}, dbc];
  
  (*Preparation of Dirichlet boundary conditions for u*)
  
  bndedges = R["BoundaryElements"][[1, 1]];
  bndvertices = Sort@DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[bndedges]];
  bpts = R["Coordinates"][[bndvertices]];
  b = ConstantArray[0., Length[R["Coordinates"]]];
  b[[bndvertices]] = -0.5 Log[
     Total[(bpts - ConstantArray[z0, Length[bpts]])^2, {2}]];
  
  (*Solving the system and creating an interpolating function*)
  
  solver = LinearSolve[stiffness, Method -> "Pardiso"];
  uvals = solver[b];
  ufun = ElementMeshInterpolation[{R}, uvals];
  (*Preparation of Neumann boundary conditions for v*)
  gradu = {x, y} |-> Evaluate[D[ufun[x, y], {{x, y}, 1}]];
  J = N@RotationMatrix[Pi/2];
  p = R["Coordinates"];
  {i, j} = Transpose[R["BoundaryElements"][[1, 1]]];
  normalprojections = 
   MapThreadDot[
    R["BoundaryNormals"][[
     1]], (gradu @@@ (0.5 (p[[i]] + p[[j]]))) . (-J)];
  boundaryedgelengts = Sqrt[Total[(p[[i]] - p[[j]])^2, {2}]];
  {\[Alpha], \[Beta]} = Transpose[bndedges];
  vertexbndedgeconnectivity = 
   SparseArray[
    Transpose[{Join[\[Alpha], \[Beta]], 
       Join[Range[Length[\[Alpha]]], Range[Length[\[Beta]]]]}] -> 
     1, {Length[p], Length[bndedges]}];
  
  (*Solving the system and creating an interpolating function*)
  
  b = vertexbndedgeconnectivity . (normalprojections \
boundaryedgelengts);
  vvals = solver[b];
  vfun = ElementMeshInterpolation[{R}, vvals];
  {x, y} |-> 
   Evaluate[
    ComplexExpand[
     ReIm[((x + I y) - (z0[[1]] + I z0[[2]])) Exp[
        ufun[x, y]] (Cos[vfun[x, y]] + I  Sin[vfun[x, y]])]]]];
```

We use function `f` at `reg1, reg2` as follows

```
f1 = f[reg1];

With[{R = 
   ToElementMesh[reg1, "MeshOrder" -> 1, 
    "MaxBoundaryCellMeasure" -> .01, "MaxCellMeasure" -> .001]}, 
 p = R["Coordinates"];
 tex = ColorData["BrightBands", "Image"];
 texcoords = 
  Transpose[{Total[(f1 @@@ p)^2, {2}], ConstantArray[0.5, Length[p]]}];
 g1 = {Graphics[{Texture[tex], 
     ElementMeshToGraphicsComplex[R, 
      VertexTextureCoordinates -> texcoords]}, PlotRange -> All], 
   Graphics[{Texture[tex], 
     ElementMeshToGraphicsComplex[R, 
      VertexTextureCoordinates -> texcoords, 
      "CoordinateConversion" -> (f1 @@@ # &)]}]}]
```

[image: Figure 1]

```
f2 = f[reg2];

With[{R = 
   ToElementMesh[reg2, "MeshOrder" -> 1, 
    "MaxBoundaryCellMeasure" -> .01, "MaxCellMeasure" -> .001]}, 
 p = R["Coordinates"];
 tex = ColorData["BrightBands", "Image"];
 texcoords = 
  Transpose[{Total[(f2 @@@ p)^2, {2}], ConstantArray[0.5, Length[p]]}];
 g1 = {Graphics[{Texture[tex], 
     ElementMeshToGraphicsComplex[R, 
      VertexTextureCoordinates -> texcoords]}, PlotRange -> All], 
   Graphics[{Texture[tex], 
     ElementMeshToGraphicsComplex[R, 
      VertexTextureCoordinates -> texcoords, 
      "CoordinateConversion" -> (f2 @@@ # &)]}]}]
```

[image: Figure 2]

Nothing new above, but now we can map `reg2` to `reg1` using `FindRoot`

```
z0 = N@RegionCentroid[reg2];

ps = Sort[p, Norm[# - z0] &];

ds = f2[#[[1]], #[[2]]] & /@ ps;

z1 = N@RegionCentroid[reg1];
ps1 = Table[{x, y} /. 
    Quiet@FindRoot[
      f1[x, y] == ds[[i]], {x, z1[[1]]}, {y, z1[[2]]}], {i, 
    Length[ds]}];
```

Visualization

```
kmax = First[Last[Length[ps] // FactorInteger]];

nmax = Length[ps]/kmax;

{ListPlot[
  Table[Take[ps, {kmax  i + 1, kmax  (i + 1)}], {i, 0, nmax - 1}], 
  PlotStyle -> cl], 
 ListPlot[
  Table[Take[ps1, {kmax  i + 1, kmax  (i + 1)}], {i, 0, nmax - 1}], 
  AspectRatio -> 1, PlotStyle -> cl, PlotLegends -> Automatic]}
```

[image: Figure 3]

We also can check how parts of `reg2` map at `reg`

```
cl = {Red, Orange, Green, Blue, Black, Gray};

Table[{ListPlot[Take[ps, {kmax  i + 1, kmax  (i + 1)}], 
   PlotStyle -> cl[[i + 1]]], 
  ListPlot[Take[ps1, {kmax  i + 1, kmax  (i + 1)}], AspectRatio -> 1, 
   PlotStyle -> cl[[i + 1]]]}, {i, 0, nmax - 1}]
```

[image: Figure 4]

**Update 1**. Given the pictures that the user cvgmt provided us (thanks to him), we need to check how Schumacher's code calculates the functions `ufun, vfun`. For this we used `NDSolve` and our code with PI algorithm implemented in it - see paper [Numerical Conformal Mapping with Rational Functions](https://doi.org/10.1007/s40315-020-00325-w). `NDSolve` code is very simple

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
reg1 = Triangle[{{2, 1}, {2, 3}, {0, 4}}]; reg2 = 
 ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^3 < 2 && y > x^2, {x, y}];

z1 = N@RegionCentroid[reg1]; R1 = 
 ToElementMesh[reg1, "MaxBoundaryCellMeasure" -> .01, 
  "MaxCellMeasure" -> .001];
U1 = NDSolveValue[{-Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == 0, 
    DirichletCondition[
     u[x, y] == -.5 Log[(x - z1[[1]])^2 + (y - z1[[2]])^2], True]}, u,
    Element[{x, y}, R1]];
Plot3D[U1[x, y], Element[{x, y}, reg1], ColorFunction -> Hue]
```

The PI algorithm is based on the series expansion of a function $g(z)=u(z)+i v(z)$, where $\nabla^2 u=0$ with the Dirichlet condition $u=-\ln|z-z1|$. To compute $u,v$ we use mesh `R1` generated above:

```
bndedges = R1["BoundaryElements"][[1, 1]];
bndvertices = Sort@DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[bndedges]];
bpts = R1["Coordinates"][[bndvertices]];
b = ConstantArray[0., Length[R1["Coordinates"]]];
b0 = b[[bndvertices]] = -0.5 Log[
     Total[(bpts - ConstantArray[z1, Length[bpts]])^2, {2}]];

With[{nn = 32}, 
  Z = {x, y} |-> Table[ComplexExpand[(x + I y)^n], {n, 0, nn}]; 
  A = Array[aa, {nn + 1}]; B = Array[bb, {nn + 1}]; 
  g = {x, y} |-> ComplexExpand[(A + I B) . Z[x, y]]];

eq = -b0 + (g[#[[1]] - z1[[1]], #[[2]] - z1[[2]]] & /@ bpts) /. I -> 0;

{vec, mat} = CoefficientArrays[Join[{bb[1]}, eq], Join[A, B]];

sol = LeastSquares[mat, -vec];
With[{nn = 32}, 
  Do[aa[i] = sol[[i]]; bb[i] = sol[[nn + 1 + i]];, {i, nn + 1}]];
```

Now we can compare `U1` computed with `NDSolve`, `ufun` computed with Henrik Schumacher code (function `f` above), and function `u=Re[g[z-z1]]`

```
{Plot3D[U1[x, y], Element[{x, y}, reg1], ColorFunction -> Hue], 
 Plot3D[ufun[x, y], Element[{x, y}, reg1], ColorFunction -> Hue], 
 Plot3D[Evaluate[g[x - z1[[1]], y - z1[[2]]]] // Re, 
  Element[{x, y}, reg1], ColorFunction -> Hue]}
```

Fortunately all 3 functions look same
[image: Figure 6]

But unfortunately functions `vfun` and `Im[g[z-z1]]` are differ

```
{Plot3D[vfun[x, y], Element[{x, y}, reg1], ColorFunction -> Hue], 
 Plot3D[Evaluate[g[x - z1[[1]], y - z1[[2]]]] // Im, 
  Element[{x, y}, reg1], ColorFunction -> Hue]}
```

[image: Figure 7]
Using `g[z]` computed above we can define conformal mapping `reg1` on the unit disk as follows

```
f1p = {x, y} |-> 
   ReIm[Evaluate[
     ComplexExpand[((x + I y) - (z1[[1]] + I  z1[[2]]))  Exp[
        g[x - z1[[1]], y - z1[[2]]]] ]]];
```

Finally we test `f1p` using code provided by cvgmt

```
disktoreg1 = 
  ParametricPlot[{x, y}, {x, y} \[Element] reg1, 
   MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y}, 
      Norm@{Indexed[f1p[x, y], 1], Indexed[f1p[x, y], 2]}], 
     Function[{x, y}, 
      ArcTan @@ {Indexed[f1p[x, y], 1], Indexed[f1p[x, y], 2]}]}, 
   Frame -> False, Axes -> False, Mesh -> {30, 30}];
reg1todisk = 
  ParametricPlot[f1p[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] reg1, 
   MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y}, Norm@{x, y}], 
     Function[{x, y}, ArcTan @@ {x, y}]}, Frame -> False, 
   Axes -> False, Mesh -> {30, 30}];
GraphicsRow[{disktoreg1, reg1todisk}]
```

[image: Figure 8]

Now it looks like conformal map since all grid lines are orthogonal.
It is clear that function `vfun` computed with higher error and we need to improve code for `f`. On the other hand we can use more simple approach based on PI algorithm.

The result of the `reg2`.
[image]

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151172/discussion-on-answer-by-alex-trounev-how-to-find-the-conformal-mapping-between-t); please do not continue the discussion here.**

Comment: (+1) Interesting. I am not really surprised that my FEM model is not really accurate in the corners. But I don't get why `vfun` is so much off from what it should be. (I will have to think about this at a later time.)

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I'm also very surprised. I'm guessing there's a routine bug in the code there.

Comment: Add the picture of the `reg2`.

Comment: @cvgmt Thank you very much.  I also calculated these pictures, but I could not yet fully calculate the inverse transformation.

Answer (score 12):

### Updated

- We use `schwarz christoffel formula for triangle`.
  $$ \int_{0}^{z} (\zeta-a_1)^{\alpha_1-1} (\zeta-a_1)^{\alpha_2-1}\,\mathrm{d}\zeta$$
- To integrate such integral, we set `Assumptions -> {Im[z] > 0}` since we mapping the upper plane to the triangle.
- And we use `(z - (u + I*v))/(z - (u - I*v))` mapping the upper plane to the disk and find its inversion.
- The final mapping is the disk to triangle.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
a1 = 0;
a2 = 1;
a3 = ∞;
{a, b, c} = {{2, 1}, {2, 3}, {0, 4}};
(*{a,b,c}=RandomPolygon[3][[1]];*)
{w1, w2, w3} = {a, b, c} . {1, I};
center = Mean[{w1, w2, w3}];
tri = Triangle[{a, b, c}];
{α1, α2, α3} = {VectorAngle[b - a, c - a], VectorAngle[c - b, a - b], 
  VectorAngle[a - c, b - c]}/π;
f[z_] = A + 
   B*Simplify[
     Integrate[(ζ - a1)^(α1 - 1) (ζ - 
          a2)^(α2 - 1), {ζ, 0, z}, 
      Assumptions -> {Im[z] > 0}]];
sol = NSolve[{f[a1] == w1, f[a2] == w2}];
F[z_] = f[z] /. sol[[1]];
{F[a1], F[a2], Limit[F[t], t -> ∞]} == {w1, w2, 
  w3};(*True*)sol1 = 
 z /. FindRoot[F[z] == center, {z, 1}][[1]] // ReIm;
disk2upper[
   w_] = (z /. Solve[(z - (u + I*v))/(z - (u - I*v)) == w, z][[1]]) /. 
   Thread[{u, v} -> sol1];
(*ParametricPlot[ReIm[disk2upper[x+I*y]]//Evaluate,{x,y}∈\
Disk[{0,0},1 - 10^-10],Mesh->30]*)
disk2triangle[x_, y_] = ReIm[F@disk2upper[x + I*y]];
ParametricPlot[
 disk2triangle[x, y], {x, y} ∈ 
  BoundaryDiscretizeRegion@Disk[{0, 0}, 1 - 10^-10], PlotStyle -> None, 
 BoundaryStyle -> None, 
 MeshFunctions -> {Norm@{#3, #4} &, ArcTan @@ {#3, #4} &}, Mesh -> 30,
  Prolog -> {FaceForm[LightBlue], EdgeForm[Cyan], tri}, 
 PlotRange -> RegionBounds[tri], PlotPoints -> 60, MaxRecursion -> 2]

(* the polar coordinate of triangle to disk *)
(* ParametricPlot[{x, y}, {x, y} ∈ Disk[{0, 0}, 1 - 10^-10], 
 MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y}, 
    Norm@{Indexed[disk2triangle[x, y], 1], 
      Indexed[disk2triangle[x, y], 2]}], 
   Function[{x, y}, 
    ArcTan @@ {Indexed[disk2triangle[x, y], 1], 
      Indexed[disk2triangle[x, y], 2]}]}, Frame -> False, 
 Axes -> False, Mesh -> {30, 30}]
*)
```

[image]

### Original

- Not an answer.
- Here we draw the polar coordinate orthogrnal lines on `Disk[]` and map to `reg1`.  We found that the `f1` seems not preserve the angle of orthogrnal lines. ( it means `90 Degree`)
- The `f1=f[reg1]` where `f` in the answer of
  @AlexTrounev https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/297116/72111 or the `f1` is equal to the `f` in the answer of @HenrikSchumacher https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/178333/72111 when we replace `R` with `reg1`.

```
f1 = f[reg1];
disktoreg1 = 
  ParametricPlot[{x, y}, {x, y} ∈ reg1, 
   MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y}, 
      Norm@{Indexed[f1[x, y], 1], Indexed[f1[x, y], 2]}], 
     Function[{x, y}, 
      ArcTan @@ {Indexed[f1[x, y], 1], Indexed[f1[x, y], 2]}]}, 
   Frame -> False, Axes -> False, Mesh -> {30, 30}];
reg1todisk = 
  ParametricPlot[f1[x, y], {x, y} ∈ reg1, 
   MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y}, Norm@{x, y}], 
     Function[{x, y}, ArcTan @@ {x, y}]}, Frame -> False, 
   Axes -> False, Mesh -> {30, 30}];
GraphicsRow[{disktoreg1, reg1todisk}]
```

[image]

- We check two mesh lines `Mesh -> 2`.

[image]

Comment: Please indicate what  the right angle  you mean.

Comment: By this way we can’t see it since you using too rough mesh.

Comment: @AlexTrounev To check the conformal mapping, we only need to check two orthogonal lines.

Comment: @cvgmt We need to check two orthogonal lines in a point ;)

Comment: @cvgmt: As I see, the angles at the centre of the disk are preserved.

Comment: @cvgmt: What is `f`? Is it the function from Alex Trounev's answer? If so then I think you should mention it in your answer.

Comment: How is it possible that the straight radial lines on the circle are still straight lines on the triangle??? The conformal map surely must change those radial lines to curves on the triangle otherwise the angles could not be preserved.

Comment: @cvgmt Please,  see Update 1 to my answer.

Comment: @AlexTrounev  Wonderful!

Comment: @cvgmt In your Schwarz-Christoffel formula implementation the triangle map looks like not complete. Is it `ParametricPlot` issues?

Comment: @AlexTrounev  Since `ParametricPlot`  impossible mapping the full  upper plane to the tirangle, so  it is impossible mapping the unit disk to upper plane then to the triangle. We can see this by observe the mesh lines in all the  figures.

Comment: @Alex Trounev: The map is not incomplete. The look of the map depends on the number of mesh lines. If you choose enough number of mesh lines then they will be visible also in the corners of the triangle, but near the side of the triangle the lines will be very dense.