# Smooth Interpolation Between Curves

Tags: graphics, interpolation, animation

I'm interested in finding a way to smoothly interpolated between graphics curves (and possibly shapes as well). My current solution is not very elegant

```
(* sample some random points *)
x = RandomPoint[Disk[], 10]; 
y = RandomPoint[Disk[], 10];

(* Linear interpolation *)
curveInterp[x_, y_, func_] := Manipulate[Graphics[func[(1 - t) x + t y]], {t, 0, 1}]

(* Example *)
curveInterp[x, y, BSplineCurve]
```

[image]

This is fine for specific curves defined using the same number of points, but I would like a more general solution where curves may be defined using different numbers of points or different primitives (`Line`, `BezierCurve`, ...).

Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks

Bonus

Interpolate between regions or meshes i.e circle $\to$ square

Comment: What you did is pretty much what I did here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/59477/4999

Comment: If we have curves defined by $\phi(u)$ and $\psi(w)$, then a somewhat general interpolation between them has the form $(1-\alpha(t)) \phi(u(t)) + \alpha(t) \psi(w(t))$, where $\alpha(0)=0,\,\alpha(1)=1$, $\alpha(t)$ is usually increasing, and $u(t)$ and $w(t)$ run over the domains of $\phi$ and $\psi$ respectively. Often this is easy to do. But that doesn't look like the setup here. We don't have a parametrization like $\phi$; rather, we have an object like `BSplineCurve`. That looks harder to do. But that is what you want to do, right?

Comment: @MichaelE2 yes this is the correct setting